# Changing label on node edit form

Tags: nodes, datetime

I want to change a label/string on a node edit form for a date field.

The label is, "Show end date" - I want to change this to, "Show end date (optional)", but I can't find where this is set anywhere. My guess is that it is some sort of theming change - I took a look at the node_form and saw nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This code is compatible with Drupal 9. The label is translatable as well.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function new_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_new_type_form') {
    $form['field_add_date']['widget'][0]['#title'] = t(' Show end date (optional)');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply find the adequate form by calling [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and letting [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) print out every possible form id:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form_id);
}
```

When you found your edit form id (let's say it's `'xyz_edit'`) you might inspect the form like so:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id = 'xyz_edit') {
    dpm($form);
  }
}
```

Now find the label by doubleclicking through the `dpm` output and replace the label whith your desired text.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) [Alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

Hook_form_alter is working before your form shown
Use hook_form_alter in Your site theme template.php file.

Like your theme name is bartik,then use this function their

```
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
//Firstly get form id then use below code

if($form_id=='Your_edit_form_id'){
//here print $form and chek which field label you want to change and then alter that field //like

$form['date'][#label]='Date Field(optional)';
}


}
```

may this will help you.